# Will async operations finish before workbook is closed?

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I have searched and read the API description, but I can't find an answer whether `async` operations are forced to be completed before `LibreOffice Calc` is closed.

For example: `dispatcher.executeDispatch()` or `ThisComponent.storeToURL()` are both asynchronous operations, meaning after they are fired they continue to operate in the background. If, after executing such an operation, a call to close the current workbook (like `ActiveWorkbook.close()` in the VBA emulation) is issued and that workbook is the only workbook open, LibreOffice Calc will terminate with this call to close the workbook.

Will asynchronous operations running in the background still be completed in such a scenario?